# Invalid Directory /Users/node_modules/superagent with React Native

Tags: ios, npm, react-native

I'm getting this error `Invalid Directory /Users/node_modules/superagent` with a React Native project. I'm not sure why it would be looking for the module in this location? How can I fix this to search for the module inside the `node_modules` directory of the React Native project where it is actually located?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing but for Firebase with React Native.

Comment: Getting the same thing for the `events` module

Comment: My fix was restarting the Node server, hadn't done so since the `npm install` command

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Are you using a .babel_rc file? I have the feeling it's related to that.

Comment: How are you requiring `superagent` (assuming you're explicitly including it at all)?

Comment: @MarkAmery I'm just doing `var superagent = require('superagent');
` the same way I include all my modules.

Comment: @JWindey I don't think I am using a .babel_rc file. Should I be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is npm3. You have to downgrade it to npm2 because the flattened packages don't seem to work yet with react-native.

Comment: I was about to say "[this guy seems to have the same issue, and have reached the same conclusion about how to fix it](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4296)" but then I noticed that he was you.

Comment: Is there a specific version of npm I should use. I tried just doing `npm install -g npm@latest-2` but that didn't seem to fix anything.

Comment: Maybe try npm@2 instead of latest-2? Also don't forget to remove your node_modules folder before doing npm i again.

I also discovered this error when you run a project that contains another package.json in one of the subfolders. Verify that too.

Answer (score 2):

I may be running into a similar issue over at [Using PubNub with React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843542/using-pubnub-with-react-native/33866190#33866190)

I used nvm to downgrade to Node v4.2.2 and then npm dropped itself automatically to 2.14.7. Re-created the React Native project (using `react-native init`) so that there was no longer a flat modules directory. However, still getting the same error when requiring.

Answer (score -1):

Node js have group of possible folders that can contain modules. When you install one module sometimes module can be dependent to other modules. I spend all day to understand that. You have to install this dependancies manual. In your case `npm install -S superagent`. It is showing error as missing path in /Users/node_modules because this is the last element of array full with possible paths that can contain modules (for MAC).

Full list of paths by OS : https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-paths